Запретить [framework]
Вступление
Не так давно были выпилена метка framework (около 300 вопросов) с её фактическими синонимом фреймворк (около 60 вопросов).
Почему данные метки не должны существовать и должны быть запрещены

Вместо конкретных меток (например django, laravel) вешают просто framework. Из-за этого затрудняется поиск, а это для меток самая главная задача. Можно сделать вывод, что данные метки не просто бесполезны, а ещё и несут вред.

Так как вопросов с главной меткой было не так уж и мало, высока вероятность, что её или подобную ей создадут снова, обе метки стоит запретить (внести в чёрный список).

Внесена в так называемый Ритуал массового сожжения,то есть эта идея не новая.


Всплывающая подсказка о запрете
Если метка запрещается, то у неё высвечивается подсказка, почему она была запрещена. Сначала просто факт запрета, он для всех меток един:

Метка [название-метки] запрещена.

А потом уже конкретное предупреждение для конкретной метки. Для нашего случая я предлагаю такое:

Метка [framework] и её синоним [фреймворк] неоднозначны. Используйте метки, которые обозначают конкретные фреймворки, например [django], [laravel], [yii] и другие.

На что я ещё хотел бы обратить внимание
Нужно запретить и framework, и фреймворк.
